# Editing attributes of shapefile in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, field-calculator, editing

I have a shapefile of polygons data. In the attribute table, I have a field named as "rank".

I want to assign the values in rank field through ModelBuilder.

Are there any solutions for this?

Answer (score 3):

As [commented by @MichaelStimson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246983/editing-attributes-of-shapefile-in-modelbuilder?rq=1#comment388643_246983):

> Calculate field should be what you're after.
>   http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000004m000000

Just select the feature(s)/row(s) that you want to "edit" first.